# Redirect to the last path - PHP

Tags: php, url, redirect, path

```
<?php echo "<a href=\"".$sql_slct->f("link_url")."\" target=\"_blank\">".$sql_slct->f("link_title")."</a>"; ?>
```

the above code will produced an output like this:

```
http://localhost/msuptplportal/app/cedec/www.softboxkid.com
```

How can I redirect the user to the last path which is www.softboxkid.com everytime user click the hyperlink?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by last path, you mean the URL where the user came from, you can use that:

```
<a href="<?=$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']?>">Back</a>
```

EDIT: What I think you want is to remove the whole ...localhost... thingy. That you can do like this:

```
<?php
    $url = $sql_slct->f("link_url");
    if (0 !== stripos($url, 'http://')) {
       $url = 'http://' . $url;
    }
    echo '<a href="'.$url.'" target="_blank">'.$sql_slct->f("link_title").'</a>';
?>
```

Comment: YES! this is exactly what i'm looking for.. TQ Dimme

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as:

```
<?php echo "<a href=\"".array_pop(explode("/", $sql_slct->f("link_url")))."\" target=\"_blank\">".$sql_slct->f("link_title")."</a>"; ?>
```

This will add only last path in the link. Hope that helps